# Batch script multiple choice menu

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, variables, menu

I have multimedia file viewing software that I call in a batch script to load files using an /LOADFILES argument. This argument accepts multiple files separated by semicolons ";".

What I would like is a menu from which I can select the files I want to open.

For example :

1. Sample_01
2. Sample_02
3. Sample_03
4. Sample_04
5. Sample_05
6. All

What is your choice ?

And what we have selected ends up stored in a variable which is interpreted by the /LOADFILES argument.

For now, my script is able to open all the existing samples one after the other :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%SystemDrive%\software\sample\*"') do (
"%SystemDrive%\software\Viewer.exe" /LOADFILES="%%I"
)
pause
exit
```

But I would like it to be able to read only the samples that I have selected from a menu, **in separate instances of the program**.

I have no specific idea of about how to achieve this.

Any help would greatly help me improve my script.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please regard that Stack Overflow is not a free code/script writing service, it is expected that you put in your own efforts! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here! Once you have tried something but failed, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts!

Comment: See `choice /?` and `start /?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (very basic) script to show you the basic concept:

```
@echo off 
setlocal 
set "loadfiles="
:AddSamples
cls
echo current loadfiles: %loadfiles:~1%
echo add sample number
echo 1 - Sample_01
echo 2 - Sample_02
echo 3 - Sample_03
echo 4 - Sample_04
echo 5 - Sample_05
echo A - All and Go
echo G - Done and Go
choice /c 12345AG /m "What is your choice? "
if %errorlevel% == 1 set "loadfiles=%loadfiles%;Sample_01.mp3
if %errorlevel% == 2 set "loadfiles=%loadfiles%;Sample_02.mp3
if %errorlevel% == 3 set "loadfiles=%loadfiles%;Sample_03.mp3
if %errorlevel% == 4 set "loadfiles=%loadfiles%;Sample_04.mp3
if %errorlevel% == 5 set "loadfiles=%loadfiles%;Sample_05.mp3
if %errorlevel% == 6 set "loadfiles=;Sample_01.mp3;Sample_02.mp3;Sample_03.mp3;Sample_04.mp3;Sample_05.mp3" & goto :continue
if %errorlevel% == 7 goto :continue
goto :AddSamples
:Continue
set "loadfiles=%loadfiles:~1%"
"%SystemDrive%\software\Viewer.exe" /LOADFILES=%loadfiles%
```