# Batch file keeps crashing at if statement

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd, goto

I am making a simple text game. Everything works fine until it gets to the if statement. I do not know what i am doing wrong.

```
@echo off

title Text Adventures

echo "What is your name?"

set /p name=

echo "That was a bad crash. Are you hurt, %name%?"

echo.

echo Y/N

set /p answer=

if %answer% equ y goto hurt

:hurt

echo.

echo "I see. That's a gnarly gash you've got there!"
```

Comment: You can only use `EQU` and other string comparisons by using the `IF /I` switch

Comment: You should amend your `SET /P` command to ask the question of the user since a separate echo is unnecessary as `SET /P` allows this form `SET /P "VARIABLE=Test to Display to User"`

Comment: Similarly I would use `CHOICE` instead of the `SET /P` for the choice because it's simple to use for making a quick choice of 1 letter responses

Comment: Can you give me an example, I am new to the batch language.

Comment: `choice /?` gives you some examples.

Comment: i still don't understand how to make things happen when a choice is made. please give me an example

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62408439/2152082)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add pause

```
@echo off

title Text Adventures

echo "What is your name?"

set /p name=

echo "That was a bad crash. Are you hurt, %name%?"

echo.

echo Y/N

set /p answer=

if %answer% equ y goto hurt

:hurt

echo.

echo "I see. That's a gnarly gash you've got there!"

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have re-written this to be in a form that uses Functions and uses the suggestions I provided to the original post as comments.

You know I assumed incorrectly that you had a purpose to using the labels, but given the way the question has give I think you would do well to not bother with them.

Here is a no-labels version:

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  echo off
  title Text Adventures
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
 ECHO. The Script Ended!
 PAUSE
 EXIT /B
)

:Main

  set /p "name=What is Your Name?"
  ECHO.
  CHOICE /M "That was a bad crash. Are you hurt, %name%?"
  
  If %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (
    echo.
    echo "I see. That's a gnarly gash you've got there!"
  ) ELSE (
    echo.
    echo "Oh Good!"
  )
  PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

Here is the labels version. (I removed the comments explaining how it works and why the code is there so it isn't so cluttered for you.)

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  echo off
  title Text Adventures
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
 ECHO. The Script Ended!
 PAUSE
 EXIT /B
)

:Main

  set /p "name=What is Your Name?"
  ECHO.
  CHOICE /M "That was a bad crash. Are you hurt, %name%?"
  
  If %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (
    CALL :Hurt
  ) ELSE (
    CALL :NotHurt
  )
  PAUSE
GOTO :EOF

:Hurt
  echo.
  echo "I see. That's a gnarly gash you've got there!"
GOTO :EOF

:NotHurt
  echo.
  echo "Oh Good!"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: i need to learn more. but im sure it works so ill check it

Comment: Why are you using functions for something you only do once?

Comment: @SomethingDark That is a better question for OP.  OP is only giving a snippet, if he only needed to write those lines then the sub functions he was using `GOTO`s to reach do seem entirely unnecessary unless he plans to do more with them later.  I'm simply giving him the benefit of the doubt that he actually wants to do something more complex there and suggesting he `CALL`s the functions instead of `GOTO`s to them.

Comment: @JosephZamora `So... not to be mean, but your answer sucks. i looked at it again and i just forgot to add pause at the end. you made it WAY too complicated. – Joseph Zamora yesterday`  Well If you weren't trying to be mean you could easily have phrased your comment to be less mean.  I'm actually fairly surprised and a bit hurt by your lack of appreciation for genuine effort to help you.  As for your opinion on my help, well, some people can't tell the good from the bad I guess.  FWIW I am trying to put some good practice to your code, So I suppose I could echo your sentiment in kind.

Comment: @JosephZamora You will find that your existing coding does not allow ou to change or re-use what you are doing, the form I used will allow you to create modules and reference them as needed, and is cleaner, your code is also using `GOTO` statements which are best to be avoided unless there is a solid reason to use them which is only a few edge cases such as `GOTO :EOF` which goes to the End of File reference, and allows you to stop executing in sequence and return out f a function.

Comment: @JosephZamora your code as written will echo the information under hurt even if you are not hurt, unless you write another bit of stuff there and another goto to try to move on, and this leads to what is commonly called "Spaghetti code" because it is unstructured and hard to maintain.  I would love to explain anything you need to learn about this code in detail so it's easier for you to follow, I attempted to do tis in the code itself using the `REM` statements to comment it for you, but it may not have been enough.

Comment: @BenPersonick I know. But that wasn't my problem.

Comment: @JosephZamora Your question turned out to be more than a bit unclear in stating the issue as you only wanted to pause but that was not what you said you just said it was working until the if.  So we all gave you better options because of the many issues which you code can cause.  The code I wrote is clean and resolves the issues your example presented.  You chose to use labels (which are essentially functions) but You don't need them at all if you just want to echo a different lines, so you should remove them if you aren't going to use them correctly as they just can give you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing I prefer by far using choice, and frequently use my menu macro that returns the selected option as a string in the variable `option`

below is a shell script that demonstrates the usage of a few macro's I frequently use.

```bat
@ECHO Off & Goto :main
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::                                           * Functions *                                      :::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+:
:ColorString
    (For %%C in (%~1)Do Set "rv=!rV!%/E%!#A!m%%~C%/E%0m"& Set /A "#A+=1"& IF "!#A!"=="37" (Set #A=31))
Exit /B 0
:+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+:
:ColorMenu
rem  Set /A "RR=!random! %%195 + 60","GG=!random! %%195 + 60","BB=!random! %%195 + 60"
rem  Set "%~1=%/E%38;2;!RR!;!GG!;!BB!m!%~1!%/E%0m"
 Set "rV="& IF "!#A!"=="" (Set #A=32)
 (For %%C in ("!%~1!")Do Set "rv=!rV!%/E%!#A!m%%~C%/E%0m"& Set /A "#A+=1"& IF "!#A!"=="37" (Set #A=31)) & Set "%~1=!rV!"
Exit /B 0
:+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+:
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:main                                  * Environment Definition *                                :::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Rem /* ensure correct environment for macro definitions */
 Endlocal & Setlocal DISABLEdelayedexpansion
:+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+:
 For /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd')do (Set "/E=%%a[")
:+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+:
Set "ChoList=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 Set "ColLETTERS=Set "Rv="& Set "#A=31" & (For %%A in ("$Str")Do Set "Word=%%~A" & For %%B In (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z . + - _ [ ] / \ ":")Do Set "Word=!Word:%%~B=%%~B !") & (Call :ColorString "!Word!" & Echo/!rV!)"
 Set "ColWORD/S=Set "#A=35"& Set "MSG=$Str" & For %%G in ("!MSG!")Do (For %%v in (%%~G)Do (Set "Rv="&Call :Colorstring "%%~v"& For %%x in (!Rv!)Do (Set "MSG=!MSG:%%~v=%/E%0m%%~x!")))&Echo/!MSG!"
 Set "List/D/V=Set "#$L=0"&Set "$$L="&For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (For %%G in (!$L!)Do (Set "%%~G" > Nul &Set /A "#$L+=1"))Else Set $L="
 Set "Menu=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (!DIV!&Set "CH#=0"&(Set "CHCS="&For %%G in (!Options!)Do For %%i in (!CH#!)Do (Set "CHCS=!CHCS!!ChoList:~%%i,1!"&Set "Opt[!ChoList:~%%i,1!]=%%~G"& Set "Opt=%%~G" &Call :ColorMenu Opt &<Nul Set /P "=[!ChoList:~%%i,1!] !Opt!"&Set /A "CH#+=1"&Echo/))&!DIV!& For /F "Delims=" %%o in ('Choice /N /C:!CHCS!')Do (Set "OPTION=!Opt[%%o]!"))Else Set Options="
 Set "ColLINE=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (Echo/!$C!!$Str!%/E%0m)Else Set $Str="
:+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+:
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::                                          * Script Body *                                     :::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| findstr Columns`) do Set "Console_Width=%%%W"
 Set "DIV="&For /L %%i in (2 1 %Console_Width%)Do Set "DIV=!DIV!-"
 Set "DIV=Echo/%/E%33m!DIV!%/E%0m"
 %List/D/V:$L=Colors%"Red=%/E%31m" "Yellow=%/E%33m" "Green=%/E%32m" "Blue=%/E%34m" "Purple=%/E%35m" "Cyan=%/E%36m" "White=%/E%37m" "Gray=%/E%90m" "Pink=%/E%91m" "Beige=%/E%93m" "Aqua=%/E%94m" "Magenta=%/E%95m" "Teal=%/E%96m" "Off=%/E%0m" "Black=%/E%30m"
 %List/D/V:$L=Actions%"Buy a house=Did you win the lotto" "Go for a drive=Start your engines" "Walk on the wild side=Get mauled by a lion" "Run a mile=Fit yet" "flee the realm=fall down a hole" "battle trolls=A losing battle" "puzzle a conundrum=Enigma's Stigmatised" "solve 42=life is meaningless"
 %ColLETTERS:$Str=Welcome.%
 %ColWORD/S:$Str=Hello there my friend^! How are you today.%
 %ColLINE:$C=Teal%What a world we live in^^!
 %Menu%"Buy a house" "Go for a drive" "Walk on the wild side" "Run a mile" "flee the realm" "battle trolls" "puzzle a conundrum" "solve 42"
  For %%G in ("!Option!")Do Echo/!%%~G!
```

The menu macro builds a list of choices for each argument it's supplied, using substring modification to iterate over a 36 character choice list to build the final choice options - meaning support for 36 menu options.

## Update

An additional example has been added to show a way to use the selection to display output or take actions without requiring conditional testing. Using the `List/D/V` macro to define values to options, a selected `OPTION` can be expanded directly. In the example, it's just to display output, however values can be assigned containing simple commands like `Set`, `Goto` or `call` to perform specific actions for the chosen menu option.